# MoPub "onInterstitialFailed" adListener not work when offline

Tags: interstitial, mopub, mobile-ad-mediation, skadnetwork

I am showing MoPub `Interstitial ad` between to `activities`.

> When my device online/connect with internet. Then `adListener` work
> properly.**This not work when device OFFLINE.**

**Situation:** If `ad` `not loaded` or `failed` then I want to use `Intent` there to move next `activity`. **But this `MoPubAdListener` not work when I am offline.**

Interstitial `mInterstitial.load()` in `onCreate` method

When user press back button then Interstitial ad called

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            customProgressDialogForAd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"before interstitial");
            funInterstitialLoadShow();
        } catch (Exception e){
            QuestionActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

function of Interstitial call

```
private void funInterstitialLoadShow(){
        mInterstitial.setInterstitialAdListener(new MoPubInterstitial.InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialLoaded(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "adloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mInterstitial.show();
                customProgressDialogForAd.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialFailed(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial, MoPubErrorCode moPubErrorCode) {
                customProgressDialogForAd.dismiss();
                QuestionActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                
                // PROBLEM HERE: THIS fun now work when Device is OFFLINE(NO INTERNET);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialShown(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialClicked(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {
                
            }
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {
                customProgressDialogForAd.dismiss();
                QuestionActivity.super.onBackPressed();

            }
        });
    }
```

Problem: `onInterstitialFailed` not work when device not connected with internet. [on the other hand if internet is ON in device, then sdk works properly eg if we close ad then  `onInterstitialDismissed` works]

Any Solution: Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is two way/method/type, to call MoPub's `AdListener`.**

***1st way:*** Direct call `adListener`

```
mInterstitial.setInterstitialAdListener(new MoPubInterstitial.InterstitialAdListener() { .... }
```

***2nd way:*** to call MoPub `AdListener` via `implements` in our `Activity class`

```
public class QuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MoPubInterstitial.InterstitialAdListener { ... }
```

#### Solution:

You are not using `mInterstitial.load()` with `adListener`. Without adding this line of code with `AdListener`  ,functions of `Adlistener` not works **because this line is part of `adListener`.**

```
     // ====this function (with moPub ad listener)== called when use click back button

    public void funInterstitialAdListener(){
        mInterstitial.setInterstitialAdListener(new MoPubInterstitial.InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialLoaded(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInterstitialLoaded: funAd loaded");
                customProgressDialogForAd.dismiss();
                mInterstitial.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialFailed(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial, MoPubErrorCode moPubErrorCode) {
                customProgressDialogForAd.dismiss();
                QuestionActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                Log.d(TAG, "onInterstitialFailed: ad failed to load");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialShown(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialClicked(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(MoPubInterstitial moPubInterstitial) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInterstitialDismissed: Done");
                QuestionActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        // If we not use this mInterstitial.load() code, then function of AdListener not work. 
        mInterstitial.load();
        // Must use this upper line with adListener. This line is part of AdListener.
    }
```

**Happy Coding :)**